# hide scrollbar from overflow css

Tags: css

How do i remove the scrolling bar from

```
.class{
 overflow: auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `overflow: auto;` or use `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 4):

Setting overflow: auto is actually telling it to have scroll bars.. To avoid them you need:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Is that what you're after, or do you still need the content to scroll?